# $\int_{-1/k}^{0}\left({x^n-1\over x-1}\right)^m\left[{1-x^n\over 1-x}+{x(m+1)[1-nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^n]\over (1-x)^2}\right]\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $(n,m)\ge1$

> $$\int_{-1/2}^{0}\left({x^n-1\over x-1}\right)^m\left[{1-x^n\over 1-x}+{x(m+1)[1-nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^n]\over (1-x)^2}\right]\mathrm dx=I\tag1$$
>   Using varies trial and error techniques we managed to find the closed form for $(1)$ to be
>   $$I={[(n-1)(n-2)-(-1)^n]^{m+1}\over 2^{(n-1)(m+1)+1}}$$

We are shrugged to generalised $(1)$ for $k\ge2$

How can we find the closed form for $(2)$?

> $$\int_{-1/k}^{0}\left({x^n-1\over x-1}\right)^m\left[{1-x^n\over 1-x}+{x(m+1)[1-nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^n]\over (1-x)^2}\right]\mathrm dx=J\tag2$$
>   We estimated that it still have this form
>   $$J={[F(n,k)]^{m+1}\over 2^{(n-1)(m+1)+1}}$$

Find closed form for $(1)$ was a pain staking task

Comment: Just out of interest, have you arrived at this expression after integrating by parts the integral $$\int\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^{m+1}dx$$?

Comment: No @DavidQuinn it is not from that integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider integrating by parts the integral $$\int\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^{m+1}dx$$

You get $$x\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^{m+1}-\int x(m+1)\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{1-x^n+nx^n-nx^{n-1}}{(x-1)^2}\right)dx$$

Therefore the primitive of your integral is $$x\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)^{m+1}$$

Comment: All too easy.  (+1)